# What electrical connection type is this?

Tags: light-fixture, connectors, light-bulb

A light switch used to operate a light where this connector is. The former homeowner must have taken the bulb or the fixture before I moved in and I had just assumed that it was a generic bulb during inspection.

It looks like there's two receptacles for prongs that connect directly to two wires separated from a single cable? There's room for maybe (guesstimating) a inch diameter pipe to slot onto it and a free floating plastic nut that would hold it in place

[image: unidentified connector]

Answer (score 7):

I think it's a "rope light" connector.

If you have a multimeter/voltmeter you should check if it's line voltage or low voltage. If low voltage there's a power supply somewhere between the switch and the connector.

Comment: [Right](https://www.google.com/search?q=rope+light+connector&sca_esv=571840155&rlz=1&tbm=isch).

Comment: I have one of these for my patio. It's all high voltage.  Assuming this answer is right, and all you have is the power cord from a rope light system, just throw it out.  If you want to kit out your patio or wherever, there are better modern LED systems.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very blurry image, but looks like GU10 connector for lightbulbs. These are the alternate "standard" lightbulbs you can buy in shops. If you don't like it, you can get an adapter from GU10 to screw-in one.

Comment: Doesn't look like a GU10 to me, a GU10 has slots to twist the bulb into